# Android emulator doesn't take input

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I wanted to create an android app that adds two number.

Firstly i set up the Layout design.

Secondly in the `main_activity` file i wrote the code.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.asus.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    double num1,num2, sum;
    EditText firstNumber;
    EditText secondNumber;
    TextView addResult;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //TextView addResult;

         Button btnAdd;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        addResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        //Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
                //num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber.getText().toString());
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
                //num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumber.getText().toString());
                sum = num1 + num2;
                //sum = num1 + num2;
                addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));
               // addResult.setText(Double.toString(sum));


            }
        });
    }

}
```

my code has no errors, however when i run the android emulator it doesn't take any input.

when i click on letter or number, the cursor moves a step, but no input is shown.

I have tried those solutions that i have found, but none has worked for me:

1. From advanced settings, check enable keyboard input.
2. From AVD, create a virtual device, hardware profile, check has hardware keyboard input.
3. Add in config file hw.keyboard=yes

However none of them worked for me, where is the error exactly?

This is my Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="First Number"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="Second Number:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text="Result:"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="87dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="ADD"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the Layout file.

Comment: I edited the post and added it.

Comment: Try increasing the height of the EditText views to something like 50dp.

Comment: Yes, that was the reason, thanks

Answer (score 1):

show your XML code , it might be :

```
1- you set a custom input type for Edit Text;
2- your windows/Ubuntu/mac is on a unsupported keyboard language for emulator;
3- in emulator advanced settings keyboard input is disabled ;
```

Comment: I edited the post and added the file, for number 3 i'm sure it is not disabled.

Comment: u wrote android:inputType="textPersonName" , change it to android:inputType="number"

Comment: It turned out that the textboxes were really small

Answer (score 0):

The height of the EditText are too small to display the text. So increase the height of those views or change it into `wrap_content`.